# debug error : confirm perspective switch

Tags: android, xml, debugging

when i click on button add debug error

and opens confirm perspective switch dialog box
shows error in dis line " EditText add = (EditText) d1.findViewById(R.id.add); " 
what is the mistake in my code??

xml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question1" >
    </TextView>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" >
    </EditText>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" >
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerques"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="registerques" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

java class
showing error in editext line

```
package quesansw.the1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Memo extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Dialog d1 = new Dialog(this);
        Window window = d1.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
        d1.setTitle("Register Questions");
        d1.setContentView(R.layout.memo);
        d1.show();
        Button view1 = (Button) d1.findViewById(R.id.view);
        Button add = (Button) d1.findViewById(R.id.add);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText add = (EditText) d1.findViewById(R.id.add);
                EditText view = (EditText) d1.findViewById(R.id.view);
                System.out.println(add.toString());
                System.out.println(view.toString());
            }
        });
        view1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), View.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the error say ??

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D thanku that problem is solved.another problem is occured. when click on view button(shown above code).opens a dialog box saying "confirm persective switch".                                asking "do you want to open this perspective now?"

Comment: You are working in eclipse right ? This dialog is not an error - it is just eclipse showing you the debugger tools (called the "debug perspective") - have you set a breakpoint ? Look at the left of the line - does it have a small blue something (a break point) ?

Comment: when i click view button, view.class not opening

Answer (score 0):

Probably da error in  the code is that you never defined an id "add" - you have `@+id/TextView01` in the xml "page" (you mean file - and you must tell us *which* file) but no `@+id/add`